# C++value of struct field stored in vector changes after insertion of new elements

Tags: c++, vector, struct, corruption

I have a code with a structure similar to the one below. Basically the class `Sorted` maintains a map mapping `A.key` to vectors of `A`, sorted by `A.value`. The method `process` adds the element passed parameter to the vector indexed by `A.key` in the map. In my actual code, quasi equivalent to this one, I always get one of the `A.key` stored in the map vectors that gets a huge value (140737263711184) or 0 instead of 1 or 2.

From my debugging trials I suspect it to happen when the underlying vector gets reallocated, since the vector capacity jumps from 16 to 32 when this issue occurs.

I know that the code below is not performant since structs are always inserted at the front of the vector, but this is not the point of the question (neither the last for loop with size_t instead of for-auto).

From what I understood, reallocation can invalidate references/pointers that are stored in a vector. But in my case, vectors contain elements of type `A`, not `A&` or `A*`. I don't understand how it is possible that an unsigned long field of a struct stored by value in a vector can change after the insertion of elements. I can't send the exact code and failed to reproduce the error with this example but these are the main sources of the error. If I read the data just after the 17th insert, the key of the previously first element is corrupted. I am also in a concurrent setting which explains the coarsed lock.

Any hint would be helpful!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
struct A{
    A(){}
    A(unsigned long a, unsigned long key, int value, int d, bool e)
        :a(a), key(key), value(value), d(d), e(e){}
    unsigned long   a;
    unsigned long key;
    int value;
    int d;
    bool e;
};

class Sorted{
    
    public:
        
        Sorted(std::vector<unsigned long> keys){
            for(auto &&key: keys){
                aSorted.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<A>>(key, std::vector<A>()));
            }
        }
        void process(A a){
            addInOrder(a);
        }
        std::map<unsigned long, std::vector<A>> aSorted;
    private:
        std::mutex m;
        void addInOrder(A toAdd){
            m.lock();
            std::vector<A>::iterator index = std::find_if(aSorted.at(toAdd.key).begin(),aSorted.at(toAdd.key).end(), [toAdd](A a){return toAdd.key == a.key && toAdd.value < a.value;});
            aSorted.at(toAdd.key).insert(index, toAdd);
            m.unlock();
        }
};
int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned long> keys;
    keys.push_back(1);
    keys.push_back(2);

    Sorted sorted =  Sorted(keys);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
        for(int j =30; j > 0; j--){
            sorted.process(A(i,i, j, j, false));
        }
    }
    for(int key = 1; key <= 2; key++){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < sorted.aSorted.at(key).size(); i++){ 
        A valueInVec =  sorted.aSorted.at(key).at(i);
        std::cout << "key in vec: " << valueInVec.key << " value in vec: " << valueInVec.value  << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```